# Getting deployment error while installing PCF Dev

Tags: amazon-web-services, microservices, cf-bosh, pcfdev, bosh-deployer

I am trying to install pcf dev on local machine which have window 10 using below link.

https://pivotal.io/platform/pcf-tutorials/getting-started-with-pivotal-cloud-foundry-dev/install-pcf-dev

During installation I am getting below error in deplo-pass.log

> Task 576 | 10:31:39 | Preparing deployment: Preparing deployment
>   (00:01:46) Task 576 | 10:34:11 | Preparing package compilation:
>   Finding packages to compile (00:00:01) Task 576 | 10:34:12 | Creating
>   missing vms: database/2fe9e267-1bb0-4be6-8a4b-b61e534bcd64 (0) Task
>   576 | 10:34:12 | Creating missing vms:
>   blobstore/8a9a1df4-39fe-4232-be3e-831d318bcb93 (0) Task 576 | 10:34:12
>   | Creating missing vms: control/29cf5702-030d-4cac-ac9d-5e4221562e3a
>   (0) Task 576 | 10:34:12 | Creating missing vms:
>   compute/927d5018-9f8d-4b94-aa37-fee45aef2280 (0) Task 576 | 10:34:12 |
>   Creating missing vms: router/d3df4a57-43dd-491d-91ce-c9eda8ca88f8 (0)
>   Task 576 | 10:34:46 | Creating missing vms:
>   blobstore/8a9a1df4-39fe-4232-be3e-831d318bcb93 (0) (00:00:34) Task 576
>   | 10:34:48 | Creating missing vms:
>   router/d3df4a57-43dd-491d-91ce-c9eda8ca88f8 (0) (00:00:36) Task 576 |
>   10:34:48 | Creating missing vms:
>   compute/927d5018-9f8d-4b94-aa37-fee45aef2280 (0) (00:00:36) Task 576 |
>   10:34:49 | Creating missing vms:
>   database/2fe9e267-1bb0-4be6-8a4b-b61e534bcd64 (0) (00:00:37) Task 576
>   | 10:34:57 | Creating missing vms:
>   control/29cf5702-030d-4cac-ac9d-5e4221562e3a (0) (00:00:45) Task 576 |
>   10:34:57 | Updating instance database:
>   database/2fe9e267-1bb0-4be6-8a4b-b61e534bcd64 (0) (canary) (00:06:47)
>   Task 576 | 10:41:44 | Updating instance blobstore:
>   blobstore/8a9a1df4-39fe-4232-be3e-831d318bcb93 (0) (canary) (00:01:03)
>   Task 576 | 10:42:47 | Updating instance control:
>   control/29cf5702-030d-4cac-ac9d-5e4221562e3a (0) (canary) (01:22:36)
>                       L Error: 'control/29cf5702-030d-4cac-ac9d-5e4221562e3a (0)' is not running
>   after update. Review logs for failed jobs: routing-api,
>   cloud_controller_clock, credhub Task 576 | 12:05:25 | Error:
>   'control/29cf5702-030d-4cac-ac9d-5e4221562e3a (0)' is not running
>   after update. Review logs for failed jobs: routing-api,
>   cloud_controller_clock, credhub

how to reviews logs of failing jobs? Is any ways to see logs  failed jobs: routing-api, cloud_controller_clock, credhub ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the bosh cli first. https://bosh.io/docs/cli-v2-install/

Make sure bosh is installed:

```
my-mac: bosh -v

version 6.2.1-a28042ac-2020-02-10T18:41:00Z
Succeeded
```

Set the environment variables for bosh to connect to pcf-dev:

```
 my-mac: cf dev bosh

 Usage: eval $(cf dev bosh env)
 my-mac: eval $(cf dev bosh env)
```

Ask bosh to show the name of your cf deployment, in this case **cf-66ade9481d314315358c** is the name:

```
my-mac: bosh deployments
Using environment '10.144.0.2' as client 'ops_manager'

Name                     Release(s)                         Stemcell(s)                                         Team(s)
cf-66ade9481d314315358c  binary-buildpack/1.0.30            bosh-warden-boshlite-ubuntu-xenial-go_agent/170.30  -
                         bosh-dns/1.10.0
                         bosh-dns-aliases/0.0.3
                         bpm/1.0.3
                         capi/1.71.4
                         cf-cli/1.9.0
                         cf-networking/2.18.2
                         cf-syslog-drain/8.1
                         cflinuxfs2/1.267.0
                         cflinuxfs3/0.62.0
                         consul/198
                         consul-drain/0.0.3
                         credhub/2.1.2
                         diego/2.22.1
                         dotnet-core-buildpack/2.2.5
                         garden-runc/1.18.0
                         go-buildpack/1.8.33
                         java-offline-buildpack/4.16.1
                         log-cache/2.0.1
                         loggregator/103.4
                         loggregator-agent/2.3
                         nats/26
                         nodejs-buildpack/1.6.43
                         php-buildpack/4.3.70
                         push-apps-manager-release/667.0.6
                         pxc/0.14.2
                         python-buildpack/1.6.28
                         routing/0.184.0
                         ruby-buildpack/1.7.31
                         silk/2.18.1
                         staticfile-buildpack/1.4.39
                         statsd-injector/1.5.0
                         uaa/66.0

1 deployments

Succeeded
```

Retrieve te logs with bosh using the name from the name column:

```
my-mac: bosh --deployment cf-66ade9481d314315358c logs
Using environment '10.144.0.2' as client 'ops_manager'

Using deployment 'cf-66ade9481d314315358c'

Task 784

Task 784 | 17:54:41 | Fetching logs for router/8828d2fd-10f6-4d1e-9a3f-ac3d6ef6b833 (0): Finding and packing log files
Task 784 | 17:54:41 | Fetching logs for database/e3b3bb98-1e73-41cf-be32-324280615a3b (0): Finding and packing log files
Task 784 | 17:54:41 | Fetching logs for compute/0820e2d7-998a-405a-bbea-e73a76ec26b4 (0): Finding and packing log files
Task 784 | 17:54:41 | Fetching logs for blobstore/5c3297a4-4ad0-43bc-8041-000ca8e38e28 (0): Finding and packing log files
Task 784 | 17:54:41 | Fetching logs for control/bf60350d-aab0-4db3-8cc2-05d666f5f3a8 (0): Finding and packing log files
Task 784 | 17:54:42 | Fetching logs for compute/0820e2d7-998a-405a-bbea-e73a76ec26b4 (0): Finding and packing log files (00:00:01)
Task 784 | 17:54:42 | Fetching logs for router/8828d2fd-10f6-4d1e-9a3f-ac3d6ef6b833 (0): Finding and packing log files (00:00:01)
Task 784 | 17:54:42 | Fetching logs for database/e3b3bb98-1e73-41cf-be32-324280615a3b (0): Finding and packing log files (00:00:01)
Task 784 | 17:54:42 | Fetching logs for blobstore/5c3297a4-4ad0-43bc-8041-000ca8e38e28 (0): Finding and packing log files (00:00:01)
Task 784 | 17:54:42 | Fetching logs for control/bf60350d-aab0-4db3-8cc2-05d666f5f3a8 (0): Finding and packing log files (00:00:01)
Task 784 | 17:54:43 | Fetching group of logs: Packing log files together

Task 784 Started  Sat May  9 17:54:41 UTC 2020
Task 784 Finished Sat May  9 17:54:43 UTC 2020
Task 784 Duration 00:00:02
Task 784 done

Downloading resource 'f7d8c6d3-43f8-419a-a436-53a38155af47' to '/Users/my-mac/workspace/pcf-dev/cf-66ade9481d314315358c-20200509-195443-771607.tgz'...

                                                                           0.00%
Succeeded
```

Unpack your downloaded log archive.